# Not able to update table from another table

Tags: mysql

I just did this a few hours ago, but now I'm not able to repeat my "feat".

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE TABLE sl_adr a, sl_address b
SET a.fk_adrID = b.id
WHERE a.street1 = b.street1
AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
AND a.city = b.city
AND a.fk_countryID = b.fk_countryID
```

Running this I get an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   'UPDATE TABLE sl_adr a, sl_address b
>   SET a.fk_adrID = b.id
>   WHERE a.street1 = b.'
>   at line 1

After googling and looking here , I still can't find out what is wrong.

In Toad I can see that the `a` us underlined with red. But don't understand why.

Comment: You don't normally alias the table you're updating.. aliasing comes in the `FROM` section, doesn't it? Or wait.. maybe i'm too sleepy

Comment: I've been working for almost 20 hours now.... so my head is not here - but yes, according to different searches, I'm able to use aliases.

Comment: have you tried using a different alias, seems trivial but worth a shot.

Comment: Hmmmn.. perhaps you're not actually updating any column from `sl_address`? but if you didn't want to update `sl_address`, isn't a `join` one way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is almost OK, only TABLE keyword is redundant.

```
UPDATE
  sl_adr a, sl_address b
SET
  a.fk_adrID = b.id
WHERE
  a.street1 = b.street1
  AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
  AND a.city = b.city
  AND a.fk_countryID = b.fk_countryID
```

also, this one is possible -

```
UPDATE sl_adr a
JOIN sl_address b
  ON a.street1 = b.street1
    AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
    AND a.city = b.city
    AND a.fk_countryID = b.fk_countryID
SET
  a.fk_adrID = b.id
```

Comment: Oh.... (feels stupid). This is what I get for working till 04:00 in the morning :)

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing is absolutely fine in update statements. I think the problem here is that you need to replace `UPDATE TABLE` with just `UPDATE`. Like this:

```
UPDATE sl_adr a, sl_address b
SET a.fk_adrID = b.id
WHERE a.street1 = b.street1
AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
AND a.city = b.city
AND a.fk_countryID = b.fk_countryID;
```